# convert milliseconds Integer into time formatted String

Tags: swift, formatting, nsdateformatter, nsnumberformatter, nsformatter

It might be an easy question but I am confused and need your help. 
I need to convert this:

```
let S: Int = 45296789
```

into this: "12 34 56 789"

that is to say S is the integer representing milliseconds. What I need is to format it into "`hh mm ss iii`"

One of the solution could be the following:

```
var a = S/1000/60/60
var b = S/1000/60%60
var c = S/1000 % 60
var d = S % 1000

String(format:"%02i %02i %02i %03i", a, b, c, d)
```

But what I need is a method using `NSDateFormatter()` or `NSTimeFormatter()` if it is possible.

I looked into stackoverflow but there are too many forms of solution and I could not find the one including the milliseconds. (the 789 milliseconds part)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
let s = 45296789

let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(s) / 1000)
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
formatter.dateFormat = "HH mm ss SSS"

print(formatter.stringFromDate(date))
```

Comment: You probably want "HH" for the 24-hour format instead of "hh".

Answer (score 1):

swfit 5

```
    let milliseconds = 35347634

    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: milliseconds / 1_000)

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

    print(formatter.string(from: date))
```